# Ubuntu runuser command?

Tags: ubuntu, shell-script, su, utilities, util-linux

I am creating a bash script that requires to run commands as a specific user. As a result I am using the command:

```
runuser
```

I have tested this script and it works perfectly in Ubuntu Server 14.10. However, when testing it on 14.04 and 12 I run into the following error:

```
runuser: command not found
```

This happens any time the runuser command is used.

I am using the following command to create a new user:

```
adduser --no-create-home --home "/home/$homedir" --disabled-password --gecos "$realname" "$uname" ; usermod -p "$passwd" "$uname"
```

Is there something specific that needs to be specified when creating the new user? Is there a particular dependency that is missing?

**Edits For Questions:**

Output of echo $PATH

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/loc‌​al/games
```

Output of ls -l /sbin/runuser

```
ls: cannot access /sbin/runuser: No such file or directory
```

The reason why I want to use runuser vs su is because of the following:

When using runuser I can run the following commands:

```
runuser user -c 'cd'
runuser user -c 'wget http://file.com'
```

Whereas with su I have to chain the commands like this:

```
su user -c 'cd; wget http://file.com'
```

Comment: Can't you just use `sudo -u` instead? Also, please add the output of `echo $PATH` as the user who runs `runuser` and the output of `ls -l /sbin/runuser`.

Comment: sudo -u doesn't work as well and I'm finding I have to put all the commands I need to use as 1 and separate them by ;. I'm running everything as the root user and here is the output: # echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games and # ls -l /sbin/runuser
ls: cannot access /sbin/runuser: No such file or directory

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please [edit] your question to add extra information, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments.

Comment: Edit your question with the contents of your comment about `sudo` - it will be better to read.

Comment: I've added my comments for sudo

Comment: In this particular case, isn't it easier to user `wget -P ~user http://example.net/file` instead of `cd`? Otherwise the question is valid :^)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`runuser` is a recent command, it appeared in [util-linux 2.23](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.23/v2.23-ReleaseNotes). Ubuntu 14.04 ships [util-linux 2.20](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/util-linux), so it doesn't have this command yet.

`runuser` isn't very useful. Just use `su` instead. Note that the command `runuser user -c 'cd'` doesn't actually do anything — the scope of `cd` does not extend to the next call to `runuser`. You'd have to use `runuser user -c 'cd && wget http://file.com'` anyway. Use `su user -c 'cd && wget http://file.com'` instead.

Comment: runuser is useful as it is not setuid while sudo or su are. As such it does not have the same restrictions as sudo. For example, under Ubuntu sudo configuration does not allow to pass open file descriptor to the command besides stdin/stdout/stderr even if root runs the command, while runuser does not have such restrictions. Plus `su -c` always runs a shell while `runuser -u` can run the command directly.